# I can not validate form with multi feild by variable name in laravel 5.4

Tags: validation, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4
my create form is multi feild for multi language. name of field in my form is variable:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'pages.store','files'=>true]) !!}
            @if( isset($languages) && $languages->count() > 0 )
                @foreach($languages as $language)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('subject_'.$language->code, 'subject in '.$language->name) !!}
                        <div class="form-line">
                            {!! Form::text('subject_'.$language->code,old('subject'),['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- TinyMCE -->
                    {!! Form::textarea('content_'.$language->code,'',['class'=>'tinymce']) !!}
                    <!-- #END# TinyMCE -->
                    </div>
                    @if (!$loop->last)
                        <hr class="style18">
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('save change',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and my control code:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
           $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
               'subject' => 'required|max:255',
               'content' => 'required|max:255',                
           ]);
    $languages = Languages::all();
    $page = new Page();
    $page->save(); // Eloquent

    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        $pageTrans = new PageTrans();
        $pageTrans['page_id']= $page->id;
        $pageTrans['locale'] = $language->locale;
        $pageTrans['subject'] = $request->input('subject_' . $language->code);
        $pageTrans['content'] = $request->input('content_' . $language->code);
        $pageTrans->save(); // Eloquent
    }

    return redirect(route('pages.index'));
}
```

but problem with validat and not detect feild name. Do you know of a solution or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your controller same this. I didn't test. Please let me know if have any problem on that.

```
    $languages = Languages::all();
    if( $languages->count() ){
        $data = [];
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $data['subject_'.$language->code] = 'required|max:255';
            $data['content_'.$language->code] = 'required';
        }
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $data);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect(route('pages.store'))
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }else{
            $page = new Page();
            $page->save(); // Eloquent

            foreach ($languages as $language) {
                $pageTrans = new PageTrans();
                $pageTrans['page_id']= $page->id;
                $pageTrans['locale'] = $language->locale;
                $pageTrans['subject'] = $request->input('subject_' . $language->code);
                $pageTrans['content'] = $request->input('content_' . $language->code);
                $pageTrans->save(); // Eloquent
            }
            return redirect(route('pages.index'));
        }
    }
```

Thank you!